# Rails has many through association - Using includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are 3 tables - books, users, rating

Book table contains title, id, description

rating table contains - id, value, user_id, book_id

The conditions to meet are as follows

- A book can have many ratings
- User can add many ratings
- User can add only one rating for a single book

The associations are as follows

book.rb

```
has_one :rating
has_many :users, through: :rating
```

rating.rb

```
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
 has_one :rating
 has_many :books, through: :rating
```

books_controller.rb

```
def show
  @book = Book.fetch_record(params[:id], @current_user.id)
  set_book if @book.blank?
  json_response(@book)
end
```

book.rb

```
    def self.fetch_record(id, user_id)
      joins(:rating).where("ratings.book_id = ? and ratings.user_id = ?", id, user_id).first
    end
```

Currently i am using joins to fetch the details.

How to achieve the same using includes ??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you use `has_many-though` association for any model ? user has one rating and book has one rating, so obviously respective rating object will have one book and one user. So rest is you need to correct as per you OOAD implementation.

Comment: What should be the associations for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

With either `includes` or `joins`, you can nest with a Hash for a finder method such as `find_by` or `where`:

```
Book.includes(:rating).find_by(ratings: { book_id: id, user_id: user_id }
# or
Book.includes(:rating).where(ratings: { book_id: id, user_id: user_id }.first

# nested hash also works with `joins`, just for FYI
Book.joins(:rating).where(ratings: { book_id: id, user_id: user_id }.first
```

### Trivia:

- `ratings:` in the above code should be the Table name (`ratings`) and not the association name (`rating`).
- The nested Hash can go deeper as you wish: i.e. :

  ```
  # say your `User` model `has_many :comments` having `:content` attribute

  Book.includes(rating: { user: :comments }).where(
    ratings: { users: { comments: { content: 'HELLO WORLD' } } }
  )

  # or following also works (because there are no conflicts of association names in the query
  Book.includes(rating: { user: :comments }).where(
    comments: { content: 'HELLO WORLD' }
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`references` with `includes`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).

```
  includes(:rating).references(:rating).where("ratings.book_id = ? and ratings.user_id = ?", id, user_id).first
```

Worth reading:
https://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/